# Get integer followed by string

Tags: mysql, string, integer, row

I would like to make a MySQL database view pertaining to the 'quantity' of a submission, which will be formatted like this:

```
Anderson | Wood | $897.55 : 548.78$, Quantity: 3**
....
```

There will seemingly always be a 'Quantity: " string followed by the quantity number. Is there a way to find the integer that comes after another particular string?  This way I can put the quantity in its own row and use that to dynamically find the price.

Comment: IT's not clear how you're getting the data, is it from a db?

Comment: sorry ergonaut.  That data comes from a view that I am getting from a query against a couple tables I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a string in that form, you can use `substring_index()` and `trim()`:

```
select trim(substring_index(submission, 'Quantity:', -1)) + 0
```

This splits the string at `'Quantity:`', removes the leading spaces and converts the value to an integer.